# New line in haskell IO

Tags: haskell

I am not able to print outputs in multiple lines with the following code.

```
average l = (sum l) / (fromIntegral (length l))

readDoubles s1 s2 = putStr (s1++"\n"++s2) >>
                        do x <- readDoublesHelper; return ("The average is " ++ (show (average x)) ++ " \n" ++ "The maximum is " ++ (show (maximum x)) ++ "\n" ++ "The minimum is " ++ (show (minimum x)) ++ "\n")

readDoublesHelper = putStr "Enter a number: " >>
                        do line <- getLine;
                            if line == "done"
                            then return [];
                            else do xs <- (readDoublesHelper)
                                    return ((read line :: Float): xs)

interface = readDoubles "Enter some numbers." "When finished, type ’done’. \n"
```

The output that I get is

```
*Main> interface
Enter some numbers.
When finished, type ’done’. 
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: done
"The average is 4.5 \nThe maximum is 7.0\nThe minimum is 2.0\n"
```

But I want the output to be printed like this

```
The average is 4.5 
The maximum is 7.0
The minimum is 2.0
```

Comment: When running with the ghc compiler rather than ghci, you might require `hFlush stdout` right after `putStr "Enter a number: "` for the user to see the prompt in due time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do notice `"The average is 4.5 \nThe maximum is 7.0\nThe minimum is 2.0\n"` is actually not printed

Reformatting `readDoubles`:

```hs
readDoubles s1 s2 = do
  putStr (s1++"\n"++s2)
  x <- readDoublesHelper
  return ("The average is " ++ (show (average x)) ++ " \n" ++ "The maximum is " ++ (show (maximum x)) ++ "\n" ++ "The minimum is " ++ (show (minimum x)) ++ "\n")
```

We can see that result is "returned" rather than "printed"
As the type signature of `readDoubles` is:

```
readDoubles :: String -> String -> IO String
```

It just returns a lifted string. Since `GHCi` will print out the final result of the function, you're getting `"The average is 4.5 \nThe maximum is 7.0\nThe minimum is 2.0\n"` as output (the return value of the function)

However, from you description, I guess you just like to print out the result, so it should be:

```hs
readDoubles :: String -> String -> IO ()
readDoubles s1 s2 = do
  putStr (s1++"\n"++s2)
  x <- readDoublesHelper
  putStrLn ("The average is " ++ (show (average x)) ++ " \n" ++ "The maximum is " ++ (show (maximum x)) ++ "\n" ++ "The minimum is " ++ (show (minimum x)) ++ "\n")
```